# R packages - could they contain logos of firm that made them and still be in CRAN Packages Repository?

Tags: r

R packages - could they contain logos of firm that made them and still be in CRAN Packages Repository ?  I think about logo on every plot that is produced by functions from that package ?

edition : I'm not good in interpretation of licences but CRAN Repository Policy :

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html

but it don't give much in this topic.

Comment: Can someone who voted to close care to explain why they did so? I think this is a valid question. Perhaps it should be generalized so that it is in the context of ensuring proper attribution for package authors/maintainers, but I don't see a big problem with the crux of the question...

Comment: @Chase My first reaction was simply that it was Off Topic, but I can see how others might feel differently on that score.

Comment: @Chase: I voted to close as "off-topic" because the CRAN package policy should be discussed with the CRAN maintainers and addressed on the CRAN policy page, not here.

Comment: @Chase I voted "not welcomed here" for very obvious reasons, some of them mentioned above. As I said above, a message/console printout when running the function might have been OK, a spam logo on plots produced is beyond my tolerance.

Comment: @ECII And what does you personal opinion about attitude towards the morals of open source have to do with whether this is a good Q or not? Or whether it is OT for SO? You might not like it nor it's attitude to shoving marketing in the user's face but it is clearly about submission of an R package to CRAN and that is very much part of the R software development process. Personally I think this is too localized.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich, others - thanks, I appreciate the insight. As someone who has never pushed a package to CRAN, I haven't spent any time perusing the package policy page. I agree this sort of question is a better fit for that venue, but still learned something in the process. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation found here http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html
It is most important that you cite the source of all IP, and that the file size not exceed 5mb. I don't see why they would not allow this.

Comment: I wonder if it isn't a form of advertising and if yes doesn't it violates R license ?

Comment: I don't think the GPL (under which R is released) says anything about advertising being not allowed.  The GPL *does* allow anyone to modify your code in any way (including removing the advertising!) and redistribute it freely, though ...